# send form data with API body (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, vue.js, frontend

I trying to send my form data with API body

this is my template html

```
<form class="custom-form">
              <h3 class="order-number">
                <img :src="$root.app_url + '/vendor/webkul/pwa/assets/images/coin.png'" alt="" class="coin-icon"/>
                {{ $t("want-to-use-your-points?") }}
              </h3>

              <div class="apply-points-input-row">
                <div class="control-group" :class="[points_error_message ? 'has-error' : '']">
                  <input type="number" name="points" class="control caption" v-model="points.points" :placeholder="$t('enter-points-number')"/>

                  <div class="control-error">{{ points_error_message }}</div>
                </div>

                <v-btn @click="applyPoints()" color="primary" class="main-btn" :disabled="disable_apply_points">{{ $t('apply') }}
                </v-btn>
              </div>
            </form>
```

and this is form data in my component

```
data () {
        return {
            points: {
                points: '',
            },

        }
    },
```

and this is my apply points method

```
applyPoints() {
            console.log('apply points function worked')
            var this_this = this;

            if (!this.points) {
                return;
            }
            
            this.error_message = null;
            this.disable_apply_points = true;

            this.$http.post('/api/checkout-process/cart/points', this.points).then(response => {
                console.log(response)

                this.disable_apply_points = false;
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
```

my problem is why the response data be like this
[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Vue doesn't have `$http` anymore. What are you using for ajax requests?

Comment: Vue.prototype.$http = axios;

Comment: What is the actual issue?

Comment: response success  false

Comment: Is the data not getting saved? Do you own the API endpoint? Look at your API logging, or the response body in the Chrome network tab.

Comment: no, I'm not own The API. Ok, I will check chrome network tab, thank you very much